# I made a git svn dcommit before a pull - how can I fix my repo?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

My scenario has:

- My local-machine git repo
- A remote on GitHub
- An SVN server on the LAN

The SVN server is still canonical, but is kept in parity with the GitHub repo. Other users exclusively use SVN, and I am the only git+SVN user (which simplifies things).

When I'm working on other computers (e.g. my laptop, from home, when abroad) I use git and I push/pull my commits with the GitHub repo. My commits are not put into SVN until I'm in the office.

When I'm in the office I'll do a `git pull` to bring-in any new commits from GitHub then do `git svn dcommit`, followed by a `git push -f` back to GitHub so the newly SVN-annotated commits become canon on GitHub and match SVN perfectly.

However, today I had some pending commits on my office computer - but I also had non-pulled commits too - and I don't know how to fix it.

At 9AM this morning, before running any commands anyhere, my repos looked like this:

```
o = Normal Git commit, lacking SVN annotation
* = SVN-annotated Git commit

GitHub
*---*---*---*---o---o---o---o---o
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I

Local computer git repo
*---*---*---*---o---o
A   B   C   D   E   F

SVN
*---*---*---*
A   B   C   D
```

Explanation: I had two commits, `E` and `F` that were in my local computer repo that were previously pulled from GitHub, these commits were not yet `dcommit`'d to SVN.

I made a mistake this morning in that I immediately ran `git svn dcommit` on my local computer without first running `git pull`. Running `git svn dcommit` caused the repos to enter this state:

```
GitHub
*---*---*---*---o---o---o---o---o
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I

Local computer git repo
*---*---*---*---*---*
A   B   C   D   E'  F'

SVN
*---*---*---*---*---*
A   B   C   D   E'  F'
```

Note that `E` and `F` are now `E'` and `F'` because they have been modified by `git svn` to be an SVN-annotated commit (so it has a different commit hash, even though it represents the same codebase state). My original `E` and `F` remain unchanged in GitHub.

My computer does a `git fetch` in the background anyway so I now have the GitHub commits `E` through `I` on my computer, and GitKraken shows me how I now have side-by-side branches that diverge after commit `D`:

```
Local computer git repo:

*---*---*---*---*---* (master)
A   B   C   D   E'  F'
             \
              \-o---o---o---o---o (remote-master)
                E   F   G   H   I
```

How can I fix this? (As Git-SVN annotated commits are effectively immutable).

I think what I want to do is reparent `G` after `F'` and so ignore `E` and `F`, then run `git svn dcommit` and then do a `git push -f` back to GitHub.

...problem is, I don't know how to reparent `G` - I'm looking at commands like `cherrypick` but that doesn't seem to be what I'm after, and GitKraken won't let me `rebase` (it isn't a menu option for anything in the `remote-master` branch).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use command line?

```
git rebase F I --onto master
```

I.e. rebase commits from after (not including) F up to (including) I onto master.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways that should be fine.

```
git cherry-pick master..remote-master
```

will cherry-pick all commits that are in `remote-master` but not in `master` and as `E` and `F` introduce the same changes as `E'` and `F'`, the commits will be empty and you can skip them.
You can of course also directly do

```
git cherry-pick F..remote-master
```

---

```
git rebase master remote-master
```

should also work. It tries to apply all commits that are in `remote-master` but not in `master` onto `master`. The commits that do not change anything `E'` and `F'` should be skipped automatically as their changes are already in that branch.
Alternatively you can of course also do

```
git rebase --onto master F remote-master
```

---

```
git pull --rebase
```

should also work just like `git rebase master remote-master`.

As you always need a rewritten linear history to talk to the SVN repository cleanly, you should maybe change the configuration so that a `pull` automatically does a `rebase` and not a `merge`. Then you can also produce clean history to `dcommit` easily when you do commits on multiple boxes at the same time.